# How to translate a webpage from java?

Tags: java, translation

I have developed a web application in java. Now I want to put translation facility without using any outside stuff like google translator.

I want to know if there are any libraries available for language translation from English to Hindi, French, Gujarati, etc ? Any alternative solutions?

Comment: By "translation facility" do you mean you want to allow users to dynamically provide text that is translated or you just want to translate all your program menus, dialogs etc?

Comment: yes, i want to translate dynamic data of my site.that may be requested by user for language translation or may be recommendation based on localization.But, i dont know either any library available or not excpept Google Translation API.

Answer (score 4):

The typical solution to this is to have your code look up all strings to be translated in a ResourceBundle, where you then manually enter translations for all languages supported.

Have a look at the internationalization section of the Sun Java Tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the [Google transalation API's](http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-java-client/). You can use the classes present in the API, from your java code.

Comment: "without using any outside stuff"?

Comment: He specified libraries. So even API's wont do ?? In that case, this might not be what he is looking for.